# How to lint GitHub Actions custom action files

Tags: github-actions, lint

When defining workflows for GitHub Actions, you can define [custom actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/about-custom-actions), in order to share logic between workflows.

When working a lot on custom action files, having a linter that validate the syntax inside those files would be great, specifically a linter that could be run in a GitHub Actions workflow of its own when opening Pull Requests that changes these custom actions files.

Is there such a linter?

Pure YAML linters are not enough since GitHub Actions files have their own peculiarities (like `${{ ... }}`, or the expression syntax in `if:`)

I have found [actionlint](https://github.com/rhysd/actionlint/), but despite its name, it [only works on workflow files](https://github.com/rhysd/actionlint/issues/350), and not on action files.

I am looking for a free to use action or library or executable that does the linting, not a GitHub App.